How to bind mount in devcontainer sidecar using docker-compose
I'm trying to wrap my head around Dev Containers and the configuration using docker-compose. My ultimate goal is to setup 3 services (those to be developed) together with supporting containers for cache (Redis), secrets (Vault) and database (couchdb).
For starters I went for one service and one database. These are the files so far:
devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "Node.js & couch",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
                "msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome",
                "oderwat.indent-rainbow"
            ]
        }
    },
    "forwardPorts": [
        3000,
        5984
    ]
}

Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/javascript-node:1-20-bullseye

# [Optional] Uncomment this section to install additional OS packages.
# RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
#     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends <your-package-list-here>

# [Optional] Uncomment if you want to install an additional version of node using nvm
# ARG EXTRA_NODE_VERSION=10
# RUN su node -c "source /usr/local/share/nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install ${EXTRA_NODE_VERSION}"

# [Optional] Uncomment if you want to install more global node modules
# RUN su node -c "npm install -g <your-package-list-here>"

docker-compose.yml (working version)
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    container_name: nodejs
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached
    command: sleep infinity
    network_mode: service:couchdb
    depends_on:
      - couchdb

  couchdb:
    image: couchdb:latest
    container_name: couchdb
    environment:
      COUCHDB_USER: admin
      COUCHDB_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - couchdb_data:/opt/couchdb/data
      - couchdb_etc:/opt/couchdb/etc
      - couchdb_logs:/opt/couchdb/logs
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  couchdb_data:
  couchdb_etc:
  couchdb_logs:

The problem
I'd like to change the couchdb volume mounts to bind mounts, so I changed the docker-compose.yml file and created directories in the project root
docker-compose.yml (bind mount attempt)
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    container_name: nodejs
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached
    command: sleep infinity
    network_mode: service:couchdb
    depends_on:
      - couchdb

  couchdb:
    image: couchdb:latest
    container_name: couchdb
    environment:
      COUCHDB_USER: admin
      COUCHDB_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../couchdb/etc
        target: /opt/couchdb/etc
      - type: bind
        source: ../couchdb/data
        target: /opt/couchdb/data
      - type: bind
        source: ../couchdb/logs
        target: /opt/couchdb/logs
    restart: unless-stopped

When I now start the dev container in VS code it fails
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container couchdb  Recreated                                            0.1s 
 ✔ Container nodejs   Created                                              0.0s 
[1621 ms] Log: startEventSeen#data {"status":"start","id":"72f4578c7b7dd475cccaf9e9bf0d7c741644ac9142737d186f72c28cf9d42cf8","from":"couchdb:latest","Type":"container","Action":"start","Actor":{"ID":"72f4578c7b7dd475cccaf9e9bf0d7c741644ac9142737d186f72c28cf9d42cf8","Attributes":{"com.docker.compose.config-hash":"60fe02fd8218abec02551b542eff06fa8db1f0d776d3ce8a477ce572869861d1","com.docker.compose.container-number":"1","com.docker.compose.depends_on":"","com.docker.compose.image":"sha256:4158510fdd76185be535e81514159eeeb23941484eb43479a99b9bebde744489","com.docker.compose.oneoff":"False","com.docker.compose.project":"experiment-1_devcontainer","com.docker.compose.project.config_files":"/Users/stw/Code/experiment-1/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml,/Users/stw/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1714897176975.yml,/Users/stw/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1714897177202-80abdcf5-d1db-4aa0-83e6-777de6a3af4e.yml","com.docker.compose.project.working_dir":"/Users/stw/Code/experiment-1/.devcontainer","com.docker.compose.replace":"9990f70644b1ce863dacdd6f7297b5a8c9f3da5d6c02d2531d7c0f0d0a387517","com.docker.compose.service":"co[+] Running 2/2ker.compose.version":"2.23.3","image":"couchdb:latest","maintaine
 ✔ Container couchdb  Started                                              0.1s 
 ✔ Container nodejs   Created                                              0.0s 
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to create new parent process: namespace path: lstat /proc/26894/ns/net: no such file or directory: unknown
[1670 ms] Stop (438 ms): Run: docker-compose --project-name experiment-1_devcontainer -f /Users/stw/Code/experiment-1/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml -f /Users/stw/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1714897176975.yml -f /Users/stw/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1714897177202-80abdcf5-d1db-4aa0-83e6-777de6a3af4e.yml up -d
[1671 ms] Error: Command failed: docker-compose --project-name experiment-1_devcontainer -f /Users/stw/Code/experiment-1/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml -f /Users/stw/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1714897176975.yml -f /Users/stw/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1714897177202-80abdcf5-d1db-4aa0-83e6-777de6a3af4e.yml up -d
[1671 ms]     at QtA (/Users/stw/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:429:3379)
[1671 ms]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[1671 ms]     at async utA (/Users/stw/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:409:3486)
[1671 ms]     at async KtA (/Users/stw/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:481:3865)
[1671 ms]     at async $C (/Users/stw/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:481:4807)
[1671 ms]     at async hrA (/Users/stw/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:661:13255)
[1671 ms]     at async lrA (/Users/stw/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:661:12996)
[1675 ms] Stop (1300 ms): Run: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) /Users/stw/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /Users/stw/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-98347c9c-4b74-4630-b06f-7be281a256831714897175613 --workspace-folder /Users/stw/Code/experiment-1 --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/stw/Code/experiment-1 --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/Users/stw/Code/experiment-1/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level trace --log-format json --config /Users/stw/Code/experiment-1/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --remove-existing-container --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root
[1675 ms] Exit code 1
[1677 ms] Command failed: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) /Users/stw/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /Users/stw/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-98347c9c-4b74-4630-b06f-7be281a256831714897175613 --workspace-folder /Users/stw/Code/experiment-1 --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/stw/Code/experiment-1 --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/Users/stw/Code/experiment-1/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level trace --log-format json --config /Users/stw/Code/experiment-1/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --remove-existing-container --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root
[1678 ms] Exit code 1

What do I miss?
